# change data frame column name by set of values

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new in R. I have code for changing the data frame column name. But it's not working

```
df<-data.frame(a=c("a","b","c"),b=c(2,4,3))
temp<-data.frame()
nam<-df[1]
i<-1
while(i<=nrow(df))
{
temp[1,i]<-df[i,2]
i<-i+1
}
colnames(temp)<-nam
```

Expected output is

```
>temp
a b c
2 4 3
```

Comment: i want a,b,c as column name for "temp" dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `unlist` to transform the one-column data frame `nam` into a vector:

```
colnames(temp) <- unlist(nam)

#   a b c
# 1 2 4 3
```

A better way is to use `[[`instead of `[` when creating `nam`. This will create a vector, and you don't need `unlist`:

```
nam <- df[[1]]
colnames(temp) <- nam
```

---

By the way: You can create the new data frame based on `df` in an easier way (without loops):

```
setNames(as.data.frame(t(df[[2]])), df[[1]])
#   a b c
# 1 2 4 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
colnames(temp) = t(nam)
```

or

```
names(temp) = t(nam)
```

Comment: it is transpose.  type ?t in the r console for documentation.  unlist works as well as mentioned by @Sven Hohenstein

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column names with

```
colnames(temp) <- c("a", "b", "c")
```

the row names are analoguous

```
rownames(temp) <- c(2,4,5)
```

Comment: what exactly you meant ?

Comment: you can not only change the column names, but also the names of the rows in a dataframe